# How many possibilities of writing a natural number $M$ as a sum of $N$ natural numbers between $0$ and $M$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, integer-partitions

> How many possibilities are there of writing a natural number $M$ as a sum of $N$ natural numbers between $0$ and $M$?

For example, I need to write $4$, using $4$ numbers between $0$ and $4$. The possibilities are 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
0+0+1+3 = 4 \\
0+0+0+4 = 4 \\
1+1+1+1 = 4 .
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: So you want to count the number of **partitions** of $8$ into $4$ (non-zero) parts, or in general of $2M$ into $M$ parts.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts. There is no closed-form formula, but you can calculate the number of partitions using recurrence relations or generating functions.

Comment: The formula should be ${M+N \choose N}$, I believe.

Comment: The range of responses in Comments reflects the uncertainty whether the order of summands is considered in counting.  Your examples suggest the order doesn't matter, but it would be better to state this explicitly.  In that case you are asking about partitions of $M$ with at most $N$ parts.

Comment: Please see the problem : [link] http://www.codechef.com/JUNE15/problems/STDYTAB

Comment: The problem you've linked to at Code Chef (from last year) treats the order of summands as significant, but the challenge there is more complicated than your Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is 
\begin{equation}
p\left(M,N\right)=\binom{M+N-1}{N-1}=\frac{\left( M+N-1\right)\;!}{M\;!\left( N-1\right)\;!}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
but concerns ordered solutions $\left(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots ,x_{N}\right)$ :
\begin{equation}
x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots +x_{N}=M
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
So for $M=4$ and $N=4$
\begin{equation}
p\left(4,4\right)=\binom{4+4-1}{4-1}=\frac{7\;!}{4\;!3\;!}=\frac{7\cdot 6 \cdot 5}{3 \cdot 2}=35
\tag{3}
\end{equation}

The solutions $\left(0,1,3,0\right)$ and $\left(1,0,3,0\right)$ are considered different although they have the same summands.